# why doesn't fetch().json() errors trigger window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

the code below will not trigger window.onerror, despite json() failing because the endpoint did not return valid json, and nobody is catching the error, so why isn't window.onerror invoked? jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f287sn05/

code:

```
window.onerror=function(error){
    alert("errorhandler 1: "+error);
}
if(1){
window.addEventListener("error",function(error){
    alert("errorhandler 2: "+error);
});
}

(async function(){
let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
})();
```

Comment: Short answer is because the error occurs in a promise context. You need a try/catch for the await and catch it yourself.... https://jsfiddle.net/t4pfsn75/

Answer (score 1):

to catch errors in async functions you can use try catch blocks, check it out:

```js
(async function(){
  try{
    let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
})();
```

Comment: useful info, but it doesn't really answer the question `why` ^^