# how to propagate uncaught errors in promise contexts to window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

unlike what one may expect, the following code will not trigger the window.error handler

```
window.addEventListener("error",function(error){
    alert("uncaught error somewhere!");
});

(async function(){
let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
})();
```

(reason being "because the error occurs in a promise context" according to a comment on
this question: [why doesn't fetch().json() errors trigger window.onerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644306/why-doesnt-fetch-json-errors-trigger-window-onerror/68644498#) )

what is the correct way to explicitly propagate it to the window error handler?
this doesn't work either, for some reason it still doesn't propagate to window.error:

```
(async function(){
let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
})().catch(function(err){
    throw err;
});
```

this doesn't seem to work either (why? no idea)

```
(async function(){
let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
})().catch(function(err){
    let ev = new ErrorEvent(err.message, err);
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
});
```

and this approach fails with the error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is uninitialized.`, whatever that means

```
(async function(){
let foo= ((await ( await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json()));
})().catch(function(err){
  let ev= document.createEvent("ErrorEvent");
  ev.error=err;
  window.dispatchEvent(ev);
});
```

so.. what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `unhandledrejection` event to catch the promises error in window object instead.

**Edit:**

As fetch() will still return response object and there is no error throwing. You can throw a error when the `response.ok` is false. See function `run1` below:

The `run2` function will throw a JSON token error as the `response.ok` is false and it tries to parse the data.

You may try to run in your local environment because fiddle may wrap the error handling in the console.

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (e) {
  console.log("Error occurred: " + e.reason.message);
});

(async function run1() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error");
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unable to fetch()");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
})();

(async function run2() {
  try {
    await (await fetch("/no_json_plz_i_want_an_error")).json();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: sounds great! unfortunately i can't get that handler invoked either on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hqs6om2p/2/

Comment: @hanshenrik, I updated my answer. I hope it makes more sense to you.

Comment: oh sorry, this has been confusing me while testing your code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681822/unhandledrejection-handler-invoked-on-firefox-but-not-on-chrome

Comment: there's a chance your catch+throw approach is only required for Chrome-browsers  because of [a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1219363&q=unhandledrejection&can=2) , ie it's not required on Firefox